# How to replace files names in multiple directories with bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have multiple directories with multiple files in each:

```
folder1
   file1.jpg
   file2.jpg
   file3.jpg
folder2
   file1.jpg
   file2.jpg
   file3.jpg
```

I want to replace like this:

```
folder1
   0001.jpg
   0002.jpg
   0003.jpg
folder2
   0001.jpg
   0002.jpg
   0003.jpg
```

My bash script...

```
start_dir="/path/to/folder/"
find "$start_dir" -name '*.jpg' -type f \
  |sort \
  |while read name; do 
     ((i++))
     mv -i "$name" \
       "$(printf '%s/%04u%s' "$(dirname "$name")" $((i)) "$(basename ".jpg")")"
   done
```

doing this:

```
folder1
   0001.jpg
   0002.jpg
   0003.jpg
folder2
   0004.jpg
   0005.jpg
   0005.jpg
```

How to get that file replace starts with **0001**.jpg in each folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process each subdirectory separately in wrapped loop

```
start_dir="/tmp/start/"

find "$start_dir" -name '*' -type d \
  |sort \
  |while read folder; do

i=0
find "$folder"  -maxdepth 1  -name '*.jpg' -type f \
  |sort \
  |while read name; do 
     ((i++))
     mv -i "$name" \
       "$(printf '%s/%04u%s' "$(dirname "$name")" $((i)) "$(basename ".jpg")")"
   done

done
```

From

```
 ls -R
.:
fold1  fold2

./fold1:
43.jpg  aa.jpg  a.jpg

./fold2:
ba.jpg  bb.jpg  wbb.jpg
```

to

```
ls -R
.:
fold1  fold2

./fold1:
0001.jpg  0002.jpg  0003.jpg

./fold2:
0001.jpg  0002.jpg  0003.jpg
```

Works without collisions

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead of `((i++))`

```
if [[ $tmpdir == $(dirname $name) ]] ; then
 i=i+1;
else
  i=0;
fi
tmpdir=$(dirname $name)
```

Comment: Thanks, but im getting syntax error. Im not sure if im doing right :S

Comment: Please check my edit